# Python's regex .match() function works inconsistently with multiline strings

Tags: python

I'm writing a script in python that takes a directory containing journal entries in the form of markdown files and processes each file in order to create an object from it. These objects are appended into a list of journal entry objects. The object contains 3 fields: title, date and body.

In order to create this list of entry objects, I loop over each file in a directory and append to the list the return value of a function called `entry_create_object`, which takes the file text as an input.

```py
def load_entries(directory):
    entries = []

    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        filepath = os.path.join(directory, filename) 

        with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
            text = f.read()
            entry_object = entry_create_object(text)
            if entry_object: entries.append(entry_object)
            else: print(f"Couldn't read {filepath}")
    return entries
```

In order to create the object, I use regular expressions to find the information I need for the title and date fields. The body is just the file contents. The function returns None if it doesn't match title and date. The following code is what I use for this:

```py
def entry_create_object(ugly_entry):

    title = re.match('^# (.*)', ugly_entry)
    date = re.match('(Date:|Created at:) (\w{3}) (\d{2}), (\d{4})', ugly_entry)
    body = ugly_entry
    if not (title and date and body):
        return

    entry_object = {}
    entry_object['title'], entry_object['date'], entry_object['body'] = title, date, body

    return entry_object
```

For some reason I can't understand, my regular expression for dates works for some files but doesn't for others, even though I've been able to succesfully match what I wanted by testing my regex pattern in an online regular expression webapp such as Regexr. The title regex pattern works fine for all files.

I've found in my testing that `re.match` is very inconsistent with multiline strings overall, but I haven't been able to find a way of fixing it.

I can't see anything wrong with my pattern.

Example of file that succesfully matches both title and date:

```
# Time tracker

Created at: Oct 21, 2020 4:16 PM
Date: Oct 21, 2020

[...]
```

Example of file that fails to match date:

```
# Bad habits

Created at: Dec 6, 2020 4:24 PM
Date: Dec 6, 2020

[...]
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: That shouldn't work for either of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's decode the regex.

```
    date = re.match('(Date:|Created at:) (\w{3}) (\d{2}), (\d{4})', ugly_entry)
```

That's three letters, followed by a space, followed by 2 digits, followed by comma space, followed by 4 digits.  Given that description, can you see why the following string does not match?

```
Created at: Dec 6, 2020 4:24 PM
```

I shouldn't spoil the surprise, but you want `(\d{1,2}),`

Comment: Nah, it doesn't even get that far, as the first part of the regex doesn't match.

Comment: I assume this is not his actual code, otherwise he would never have had a match.  He must be chopping the file up into lines.